# Proportion vs contingency chi-square tests giving different p-values in Python

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, statsmodels

I have found different methods of conducting a chi-square test for A/B testing looking at users vs conversion rate of a control and a test group.

The first method uses `statsmodels` and uses `proportions_chisquare`

The second method uses `scipy` and `chi2_contingency`

It seems that `chi2_contingency` always has a higher value that proportions. Any idea for the difference and which test is more applicable for a simple A/B test?

I apologize for not including an example here is one below:

Example1 (p-value = 0.037):

```
import statsmodels.stats.proportion as proportion
import numpy as np

conv_a = 20
conv_b = 35
clicks_a = 500
clicks_b = 500
converted = np.array([conv_a, conv_b])
clicks = np.array([clicks_a,clicks_b])

chisq, pvalue, table = proportion.proportions_chisquare(converted, clicks)
print('Results are ','chisq =%.3f, pvalue = %.3f'%(chisq, pvalue))
```

Example 2 (p-value = 0.0521):

```
import numpy
import scipy.stats

control_size = 500
A_CONVERSIONS = 20
A_NO_CONVERSIONS= control_size - A_CONVERSIONS
test_size = 500
B_CONVERSIONS = 35
B_NO_CONVERSIONS = test_size - B_CONVERSIONS

data = numpy.array([[A_NO_CONVERSIONS, A_CONVERSIONS],
                    [B_NO_CONVERSIONS, B_CONVERSIONS]])

chi_square, p_value = scipy.stats.chi2_contingency(data)[:2]

print('χ²: %.4f' % chi_square)
print('p-value: %.4f' % p_value)
```

Comment: Please include sample data and code so that we can reproduce the difference. It's difficult to help with these kind of questions (why is XYZ happening?) if we don't know anything about the data and code you've been using.

Comment: Your contingency tables are different in both cases, so obviously chi-squared statistics and p-values will be different. See my example below that shows how results are consistent.

Answer (score 5):

Further to my comment above, here is a reproducible minimal example showing the use of `proportions_chisquare` from `statsmodels` and `chi2_contingency` from `scipy`. As expected, results agree.

Let's generate some sample data; data are taken from Fleiss JL, Statistical methods for rates and proportions, New York: John Wiley & Sons (1981).

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({
    "Smokers": [83, 90, 129, 70],
    "Patients": [86, 93, 136, 82]
})
```

Results from both tests are given below

```py
import statsmodels.stats.proportion as ssp
(chi2, p, arr) = ssp.proportions_chisquare(count = data.Smokers, nobs = data.sum(axis = 1))
"chi2 = %4.2f, p-value = %4.3f" % (chi2, p)
#'chi2 = 0.42, p-value = 0.936'


import scipy.stats as ss
(chi2, p, df, arr) = ss.chi2_contingency(data, correction = False)
"chi2 = %4.2f, p-value = %4.3f" % (chi2, p)
#'chi2 = 0.42, p-value = 0.936'
```

As to the difference between a chi-square test and z-test (test of equal proportions), I refer to an [excellent post on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/what-is-the-relationship-between-a-chi-squared-test-and-test-of-equal-proportion).